# Properties of $\mathbf{x_i^{T}BB^{T}x_{j}}$ with random vectors $\mathbf{x_i, x_j}$ and a trainable matrix $\mathbf{B}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, machine-learning

I'm constructing an affinity/similarity matrix $\mathbf{A}_{n,n}$ which must express some sort of relationship among a set size $n$ of random vectors $\mathbf{x_i}$ with unknown distribution $F$. For any two feature vectors $\mathbf{x_i, x_j}$ and matrix $\mathbf{B}$, which is learned/trained using the data, I compute similarity between any two $\mathbf{x_i, x_j}$:

$a_{i,j} = \mathbf{(B^{T}x_i)^{T}B^{T}x_j=x_i^{T}BB^{T}x_{j}} $

Can I prove at least some property of $\mathbf{A}$, e.g. all $a_{ij} \geq 0$, given that none of the inputs is guaranteed to be positive. Or, since $\mathbf{x_i}$ are random, something about the distribution of $a_{ij}$?

Links to publications and/or relevant theorems will do. This is for my research on Deep Learning with CT scans used for COVID-19 prediction.

Comment: Note that if $X$ is the matrix whose columns are $\mathbf x_1,\dots \mathbf x_n$, then your matrix can be written as
$$
A = X^TBB^TX.
$$
We can guarantee that this matrix will be positive semidefinite (i.e. symmetric with real, non-negative eigenvalues), but I don't think that there is more we can say

Comment: If you know the mean and covariance for the $\mathbf x_i$, then we can get some corresponding information about the mean of each of the entries $a_{ij}$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks, can you point me to some relevant theorems, e.g. why $A$ will be psd

Comment: For any matrix $M$, the matrix $A = M^TM$ is psd. In this case, we have $M = B^TX$.

Comment: Somehow I keep getting negative values in $\mathbf{A}$...

Comment: "Positive semidefinite" does **not** mean that the entries of $A$ are non-negative

Comment: Ah got it, it would be true for a scalar $z^{T}Az$ for any vector $z$.